# Making a multiclass classification problem binary during data preprocessing vs using a multiclass classifier

Tags: machine-learning, classification, multi-class

Sometimes you have a problem that presents as a multiclass problem in your data, but you only care about the result of a binary classification. E.g. you have a manufacturing process which can result in multiple different anomalies, but you only care if the produced part is good or scrap.

What I've seen done before is that the multiclass problem simply gets reduced to a binary problem in the data preprocessing step. You change the labels from e.g. "Good, Anomaly 1, Anomaly 2, ..." to "Good, Scrap".

Something that seems more intuitive to me would be using a multiclass classifier and then making the resulting predictions binary afterwards.

Using a multiclass classifier seems more intuitive to me because the different kinds of anomalies might present very differently in the features, which seems like it might throw off a binary classifier. Is there something to this? I would be grateful for any advantages/disadvantages of one vs the other you can think of.

Comment: You need to think clearly about estimation vs. forced-choice classification.  These are vastly different tasks, and classification usually [doesn’t make sense](https://fharrell.com/post/classification).

Comment: To me, binary classification is more intuitive. Such a classifier must only "know" how a good part looks like, while the multi class one needs to learn all the different anomalies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the right idea. One can easily think scenarios where first fitting a multiclass classifier and then reducing the output to binary will work better than directly fitting a binary classifier.

Just as a dummy example. I generated some data where normal (N) samples are in the origin and different anomalies (A0,..) in clusters around it; and fitted logistic regression model both using the original labels (left) and using binarized labels (right).

[image: Visualization of multiclass vs. binary classification using logistic regression]

The multiclass model can find a good decision boundary, whereas the binary classifier is completely lost as the data cannot be separated linearly. I suppose this was what you were thinking.

This proves that multiclass classifier can sometimes work better than binary classifier. I don't think this is in general true though. Couple of things to consider come to mind:

- The multiclass model is more complex. If the anomalies could be separated e.g. by linear decision boundary, the multiclass approach would add unnecessary complexity and make the model prone to overfitting.
- Related to this, maybe some of the anomaly groups contain only couple of samples. In this case some of the decision boundaries would be very poorly estimated by the multiclass classifier.
- Instead of using a multiclass classifier, you can just use a more complex model and solve the binary classification problem directly.

The only way to know which approach will work best for your particular problem is usually just to test different models. The idea of first fitting multiclass model and then reducing the output to binary might work, or not. If nothing else, the output contains more information; maybe someone cares which type of anomaly it is.